# Is p-value the same as "alpha" also, called type-I error in context of statistical significance?

Tags: p-value, inference, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have read some notes and comments on different websites . It seems that a refererence to p-value could mean that it  equals  the alpha term used frequently in basic statistics.

Comment: Editing a question to ask the opposite of its original form after an answer has been provided is not a usual behaviour on this site. When that happens it devalues the input of the members who have already answered and makes it very confusing for people following a search result to find the answer.

Comment: Regardless of the edit, the answer is still no. $\alpha$ is the *set* level of significance and $p$ the probability of a result at least as extreme as the one *observed*.

Answer (score 7):

**No**.

[Statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Statistical_test_theory) is the probability that a test correctly rejects the null hypothesis. It is 1 - the probability of a [type II error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors), which is to fail to reject a false null hypothesis.

The [alpha level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Statistical_test_theory) is the probability of falsely rejecting a true null hypothesis: a false positive or type I error.

The two concepts are related. For instance, they are both use in [sample-size](/questions/tagged/sample-size) determination (along with the effect size we want to be able to detect). However, they are different.

Comment: One more phrase is necessary in your 1st full sentence.